# How to provide base classes for authorization requirements?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-core-authorization

I've got a few authorization requirement types that are very similar. The first type takes a `string[]` of roles to check the user's role against. The second type takes a `string[]` of elevated roles that can short-circuit the handler and another `string[]` of checked roles like the first. Let's say I then have the following:

```
public abstract class RoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    internal string[] CheckedRoles { get; }

    public RoleRequirement(string[] checkedRoles)
    {
        CheckedRoles = checkedRoles;
    }
}

public abstract class ElevatedRoleRequirement : RoleRequirement
{
    internal string[] ElevatedRoles { get; }

    public ElevatedRoleRequirement(string[] elevatedRoles, string[] checkedRoles) 
    : base(checkedRoles)
    {
        ElevatedRoles = elevatedRoles;
    }
}
```

I have a few concrete variations of both types and the associated handlers accept those concrete types. The issue is DI is resolving them all as a base `RoleRequirement` even though the actual type passed to the handler is a concrete type. This causes the wrong handler to be invoked which can't deal with the given type.

I've tried registering the handlers as both singletons and scoped without benefit though I'll most likely need scoped handlers. Each look like the following:

```
 services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, SomeRoleRequirementHandler>();
 services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, SomeElevatedRoleRequirementHandler>();
```

Is it possible to design this in a way to keep this DRY?

Comment: Can you show how you register types in services configuration?

Comment: @Fabio, done. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? How come you're not using GenericPrincipal and GenericIdentity classes and decorating your routes and methods with AuthorizeAttributes? You can add multiple AuthorizeAttributes for alternatives and the policies referenced by them can require multiple claims.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, these handlers are for auth policies and added as Authorize attributes as allowed but the requirements for some of these cannot be met without imperative resource authorization. I don't see this as an issue with using GenericPrinciple or Identity, it's beyond claims.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, can a case like this be solved that way: Given `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are roles and `e` is a resource to auth against. The logical problem is: (a || b) || ((c || d) && e). I can clarify if that doesn't make sense. `e` has some properties that need to be matched on the user.

Comment: ServiceCollection will register both implementation types as a collection behind `IAuthorizationHandler`, then if some class will have collection of abstractions as constructor argument it will return a collection if singular instance expected it will return last one.